# Using .net in an IPHONE app?

Tags: asp.net, iphone, ios, cordova

could anyone please ease my misery and inform me whether its possible to use .net pages within a compiled iphone app?

I'm using Phonegap and trying to connect to alter an existing .net app to work?

Any advice would be gratefully received!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be interested in [monotouch](http://monotouch.net) -- it will let you write native iphone apps in C#. You probably can't directly port the ASP.NET pages, but you can at least port some of the code.

Answer (score 0):

Yes as a mobile web site.  If you are trying to do it as an application and not a web site, then no.

- http://dotnetslackers.com/articles/aspnet/DevelopingForTheiPhone.aspx
- http://www.asp.net/mobile/
- http://www.hanselman.com/blog/TheWeeklySourceCode28IPhoneWithASPNETMVCEdition.aspx

As per PhoneGap, seems insteresting, and you may be not able to use that for ASP.NET (from what I gather from the website), but you can just as easily get iPhone support without it.